# Debugging methods with zxing intent

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm working on an Android app that needs to scan a QR code. I'm using https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded solution on my app with a simple IntentIntegrator and a onActivityResult method to get results from scan. It's the same sample code on the README.md:

```
new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Activity


// Get the results:
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(result != null) {
    if(result.getContents() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myFunction(result.getContents());

    }
} else {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Inside of the else (when scan is achieved) I'm triggering a simple function. The issue I'm having is with debugging. When I launch the application and I use the scanner without debugging it works, the QR scans and gets the content, but my logic inside of the function is not working as intended and I need to debug with some breakpoints to figure out what's wrong. When I try running the app on debug mode the scanner gets stuck (keeps trying to autofocus the QR code) but it never actually achieves scanning or triggers any breakpoint or event. I've tried with other zxing forks and I always get this issue with debugging QR. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.